# CSV Export including row from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I am trying to export to a CSV in CakePHP.

Basically the problem that I am having is, the database is split down into multiple tables. 
One for a product, one for artists and one for users.

It is all working well apart from the fact that the Email addresses for the artists are stored in the users table, I would like these to be included in the export. I have tried adding in the appropriate header for the column (csv) and then adding the 
    $result['Users']['username'],
Row that can be seen in my full function below, however it leaves the Email fields blank. Please help!

```
function export($event_id)
{
    $this->layout = 'blank_layout';

    ini_set('max_execution_time', 600); //increase max_execution_time to 10 min if data set is very large

    //create a file
    $filename = "export_".date("Y.m.d").".csv";
    $csv_file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');

    $results = $this->Sculpture->find('all', array('conditions' => array('event_id' =>       $event_id), 'order' => 'artist_id'));

    // The column headings of your .csv file
    $header_row = array(
        "Artist",
        "Email",
        "Sculpture", 
        "Materials", 
        "Description",
        "Price",
        "Notes"
        );
    fputcsv($csv_file,$header_row,',','"');

// Each iteration of this while loop will be a row in your .csv file where each field corresponds to the heading of the column
    foreach($results as $result)
    {
    // Array indexes correspond to the field names in your db table(s)
        $row = array(
        $result['Artist']['name'],
        $result['Users']['username'],
        $result['Sculpture']['title'],
        $result['Sculpture']['materials'],
        $result['Sculpture']['description'],
        $result['Sculpture']['price'],
        $result['Sculpture']['notes'],
    );

    fputcsv($csv_file,$row,',','"');
    }

    fclose($csv_file);
}
```

Sculpture Model

```
    <?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Sculpture Model
 *
 * @property Artist $Artist
 * @property Event $Event
 */
class Sculpture extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
    'artist_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'event_id' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'title' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please tell us the name of your sculpture',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'materials' => array(
        'notempty' => array(
            'rule' => array('notempty'),
            'message' => 'Please tell us the materials used in this sculpture',
            'allowEmpty' => true,
            'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    ),
    'price' => array(
        'money' => array(
             'rule'    => array('numeric'),
            'message' => 'Please include the price of your sculpture.'
            //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            //'allowEmpty' => false,
            //'required' => false,
            //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
            //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
        ),
    )
);

public function beforeValidate()
{
    //$p = $this->data['Sculpture']['price'];

    // Get decimal place if available
    //$dec = substr(, $start)

    $this->data['Sculpture']['price'] = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", '', $this->data['Sculpture']['price']);
    return true;
}
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Artist' => array(
        'className' => 'Artist',
        'foreignKey' => 'artist_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Event' => array(
        'className' => 'Event',
        'foreignKey' => 'event_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);


/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'MediaFile' => array(
            'className' => 'MediaFile',
            'joinTable' => 'sculptures_media_files',
            'foreignKey' => 'sculpture_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'media_file_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
    )
);

}
```

NEW Error report

```
$this->loadModel('Artist');
    $artist = $this->Artist->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Artist.user_id' =>        $this->Auth->user('id'))));
    $this->set('artist_id', $artist['Artist']['id']);
EventsController::view() - APP/Controller/EventsController.php, line 78
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 486
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 92
```

NEW NEW ERROR From Sculpture Model

```
$results = $this->Sculpture->find('all', array('conditions' => array('event_id' => $event_id), 'order' => 'artist_id', 'recursive' => 2));

    debug($results); die();
```

The New error

```
$this->loadModel('Artist');
$artist = $this->Artist->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Artist.user_id' =>         $this->Auth->user('id'))));
$this->set('artist_id', $artist['Artist']['id']);
EventsController::view() - APP/Controller/EventsController.php, line 78
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 486
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 92

<div class="cake-debug-output">
<span><strong>/app/Controller/SculpturesController.php</strong> (line <strong>70</strong>)</span>
<pre class="cake-debug">
array(
    (int) 0 =&gt; array(
        &#039;Sculpture&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;id&#039; =&gt; &#039;462&#039;,
            &#039;artist_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
            &#039;event_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
            &#039;title&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
            &#039;materials&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
            &#039;description&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
            &#039;edition&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
            &#039;price&#039; =&gt; &#039;0.00&#039;,
            &#039;vat&#039; =&gt; false,
            &#039;media_file_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
            &#039;delivery&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-12-16&#039;,
            &#039;notes&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
            &#039;created&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-12-16 12:52:14&#039;,
            &#039;modified&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-12-16 12:52:14&#039;
        ),
        &#039;Artist&#039; =&gt; array(
            &#039;id&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
            &#039;name&#039; =&gt; &#039;Amanda Noble&#039;,
            &#039;website&#039; =&gt; &#039;www.thefusedgarden.co.uk&#039;,
            &#039;materials&#039; =&gt; &#039;Glass and stainless steel&#039;,
            &#039;location&#039; =&gt; &#039;Northants&#039;,
            &#039;created&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-04-30 14:53:25&#039;,
            &#039;modified&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-09 15:21:53&#039;,
            &#039;user_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;11&#039;,
            &#039;User&#039; =&gt; array(
                &#039;password&#039; =&gt; &#039;*****&#039;,
                &#039;id&#039; =&gt; &#039;11&#039;,
                &#039;username&#039; =&gt; &#039;noblept@aol.co.uk&#039;,
                &#039;role_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;4&#039;,
                &#039;created&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-01 15:26:40&#039;,
                &#039;modified&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-01 15:26:40&#039;
            ),
            &#039;Sculpture&#039; =&gt; array(
                (int) 0 =&gt; array(
                    &#039;id&#039; =&gt; &#039;138&#039;,
                    &#039;artist_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
                    &#039;event_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;2&#039;,
                    &#039;title&#039; =&gt; &#039;Midsummer Blue&#039;,
                    &#039;materials&#039; =&gt; &#039;Glass &amp; Stainless Steel&#039;,
                    &#039;description&#039; =&gt; &#039;One of 3 fused glass panels. sold either as a single panel or as a set of 3&#039;,
                    &#039;edition&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
                    &#039;price&#039; =&gt; &#039;144.00&#039;,
                    &#039;vat&#039; =&gt; false,
                    &#039;media_file_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
                    &#039;delivery&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-28&#039;,
                    &#039;notes&#039; =&gt; &#039;When sold as a set of three the price is 10% lower.
We will arrive AM, but will not require assistance to install our sculptures&#039;,
                    &#039;created&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-09 15:06:56&#039;,
                    &#039;modified&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-09 15:21:07&#039;
                ),
                (int) 1 =&gt; array(
                    &#039;id&#039; =&gt; &#039;159&#039;,
                    &#039;artist_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;1&#039;,
                    &#039;event_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;2&#039;,
                    &#039;title&#039; =&gt; &#039;Blue evening&#039;,
                    &#039;materials&#039; =&gt; &#039;Glass and Stainless Seel&#039;,
                    &#039;description&#039; =&gt; &#039;One of 3 fused glass panels sold either as a single panel or as a set of 3   ( the other 2 are Midsummer Blue and Blue Haze )&#039;,
                    &#039;edition&#039; =&gt; &#039;&#039;,
                    &#039;price&#039; =&gt; &#039;128.00&#039;,
                    &#039;vat&#039; =&gt; false,
                    &#039;media_file_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;0&#039;,
                    &#039;delivery&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-29&#039;,
                    &#039;notes&#039; =&gt; &#039;Each panel is unique as no piece of fused glass will ever be identical, but it is possible to create a similar, but not exact replica of any panel.
The images shown are of a similar sets, but the actual exhibits are still in the process of creation and an image is not available.&#039;,
                    &#039;created&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-09 15:30:53&#039;,
                    &#039;modified&#039; =&gt; &#039;2013-07-09 16:31:17&#039;
                ),
```

Comment: please post your `Sculpture` Model file so we can check the relationships and the conventions used

Comment: so try `$result['Artist']['User']['username']` instead of `$result['Users']['username']` (and remove debug)

Comment: Awesome, that has worked a treat! Thank you ever so much for your patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are following cake namning convention it should be

```
$result['User']['username'],
```

(Model name must be singular and not plural)

**edited after seeing Scuplure model file:**

Because User is related to Artist Model (and not directly to Sculpture Model) you have to set 'recursive' parameter in your find call:

```
$results = $this->Sculpture->find(
    'all', 
    array(
        'conditions' => array('event_id' => $event_id), 
        'order' => 'artist_id',
        'recursive' => 2
    )
);
```

Comment: I am unsure whether we are using the normal Cake naming convention. I have just tried your line to no avail. I did realise however that the other headers are the same as what you said.

Comment: Added that line of code caused an internal server error.

The table structure is

sculptures -> which has artist_id
artists -> which has user_id
users -> which has id

That is the column with the same identifier, thanks.

Comment: (please forget the part about Sculpture belongsTo User), just use the recursive parameter

Comment: Just using the recursive parameter leaves the csv fields blank

Comment: set de debug mode on and post the result of `debug($results)` and every warning message

Comment: Sorry for my incompetence, how do I do this?

Comment: in app/config/core.php set `Configure::write('debug', 2);` instead of `Configure::write('debug', 0);`. Then in your controller just write `debug($results)` after the row with `$results = $this->Sculpture->find(...)`

Comment: Debug log posted above

Comment: I told you to remove the belongsTo relationship between Sculpture and User. see 6 comments above: I misunderstood your relationships.

Comment: I think you edited your Sculpture model after my answer. don't do it. Just let it as it was at the beginning of this discussion. You wasn't getting any error before, so you still shouldn't get any error now if you just add the recursive parameter and nothing else. And then post what you get when you do `debug($results)`

Comment: I haven't I have put the model back to how it was, I have added the recursive parameter to the sculpture controller. The page loads fine, that is just what I see at the top. There is a lot of "jibberish" now in the .csv file but this is 12mb in size now.

Comment: so try `debug($results); die()` so we can see your $result variable before you send it to your csv.

Comment: I have added these above

Comment: of course add a semi-colon after `die()`. I forgot it but is basic php debugging.

Comment: I dont't get why you are getting an error when you told me thet the page loads fine. You should just see the content of the $results variable and nothing else.

Comment: I have just pasted in the contents of the csv file, I hope that helps